# Is a jQuery element an instance of a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

Is there a way to know if a textfield is an instance of jQuery UI Datepicker?

In example, lets say I have this code:

```
$('#item_id').datepicker();
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
if($('#item_id') IS NOT A DATEPICKER YET)
{
    $('#item_id').datepicker();
}
```

The above conditional check, of course, is in human language and not JavaScript regular code ;)

PS: I know my question is very general, but my English are not so good :(

Comment: Even without good English, you can use code examples to demonstrate what you're looking for. You'll get better community response, and better answers. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have some code to provide. Just I like to know if there is some way to know if a textfield is already assigned to datepicker plugin

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to answer something so vague. Have you read the documentation? Maybe you could at least link that in your question? As it stands, this really doesn't help the community help you.

Comment: @jmort253 what I do is just the $('element_selector').datepicker(); and What I need, is to check before that if the element is already a datepicker with some conditional check.

Comment: Merianos - I'm a programmer, so code is the easiest way to communicate. Your example made it a lot clearer and makes sense now. +1 Great question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a textfield has been applied with a JQuery UI Datepicker, it will contain a 'hasDatepicker' class.

Perhaps you can form a query like `$('#field').hasClass('hasDatepicker')` to check if the a specific textfield with id 'field' has a datepicker feature applied on it. Make sure you do the check *after* the datepicker has been applied, not *before*.

Alternatively, you can just do a check of the same classes used to apply the datepicker.

If you use `$(".applyDatepicker").datepicker();` to apply the datepicker on all textfield with 'applyDatepicker' class. Then you can just backtrack with `$('#field').hasClass('applyDatepicker')`.

Comment: Thanks !!! Was so simple, and I hadn't see that class :$ I shy. Thanks a lot anyway !!! :)